# Modular arithmetic proof without using induction

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Need some help guys I'm really unsure how to do this, can someone give me a step by step guide please?

Show that $10 \mid (3^{4n} + 50n^6 − 11)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ without using induction.

Comment: Is that $34n + 50n^6 - 11$? Because that is *never* divisible by $10$..

Comment: Isn't $34n + 50n^6 - 11$ odd for any $n \in Z+$?

Comment: OP need to edit the question, it is not clear.

Comment: I've edited the question now, sorry guys.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

$$3^{4n}+50n^6-11=81^n+50n^6-11\equiv 1^{4n}-11(\text{ mod }10)\equiv 0(\text{ mod }10).$$